# How to distribute directories?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, ubuntu

Let us say I have a list of directories:

```
archive_1
archive_2
archive_a
...
```

Is there a simple way to distribute these directories into a specified number of directories? For instance something like:

```
distribute -t10 archive_*
```

should produce 10 directories: `sub_1, sub_2, ... sub_10` and contain `total number of archive_* directories/10` in each. Something like how `split` works but for directories instead of files. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's an odds-on bet the answer is 'no'.  It wouldn't be dreadfully hard to produce one, but there are many worrying edge cases to deal with (such as 'one of the original directories has the name `sub_1`', not to mention how it is specified that the prefix for the new names is `sub_`).

Comment: If I understand you, you have a list of X directories, and you want to put them into Y sub directories where each sub directory will have around X/Y directories? Yes, it's possible, but why would you want to do that? I just need to know, so I can give you some sort of answer.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Actually, I like the way `split` does this automatically but it also accepts an optional prefix to the newly created files.

Comment: @DavidW.: The `Y` sub directories will have to be created if they don't exist. This drive is mounted as an NFS volume and I am trying to run some batch script on the files inside these directories. But because of the way I am assigned a "slice" on these machines, my batch script is timing out so this is just to split the work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a Unix command for this, but you can use a simple Python script like this. To distribute all files in a directory, invoke as `distribute.py -c10 -p sub *`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, os, shutil
from optparse import OptionParser

p = OptionParser()
p.add_option("-c", "--count", type="int", default=10,
    help="Number of dirs to distribute into", metavar="NUM")
p.add_option("-p", "--prefix", type="string", default="sub",
    help="Directory prefix", metavar="PREFIX")

(options, args) = p.parse_args()

for x in range(0, options.count):
    os.mkdir("%s_%d" % (options.prefix, x))

c = 0
for f in args:
    shutil.move(f, "%s_%d" % (options.prefix, c))
    c += 1
    c %= options.count
```

Comment: Note that this won't ensure that none of the `sub_` directories exist, and it will also include files. You can add extra checks to prevent this. Also this moves files to subdirs in a round-robin fashion.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

dirs=$(ls ${3})
for i in dirs
do
cd $i
for j in 1..$2
do
mkdir sub_$j
done
cd ..
done
```

execute it this way:

```
distribute -t 10 archive_
```